Accessing signal array in the template
In the ServiceFile I have this signal:
answerSequence = signal<string[]>(['', '', '', '']);

I get this angular signal to my Component:
answerSequence = computed(() => this.questionService.answerSequence);

In my template I want to display the 4 positions of the array separately but the syntax does not work
<p>{{ answerSequence()?.[0] }}</p>
<p>{{ answerSequence()[0] }}</p>

I use Angular 17
can anyone help with this problem?

You need to invoke your signal in the computed to return its value :
Component: answerSequence = computed(() => this.questionService.answerSequence()); 

Which will allow you to write:
{{ answerSequence()[0] }}

